# Keras - Output Simple Inputs to Test Layers

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

Is it possible to use the layer functions in Keras without compiling and using a neural network? I would like to learn about what certain functions do by passing them a simple numpy array and looking at the output - is this possible?

I tried the following to see how a 1D max pooling worked looking at:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/pooling.py#L54

```
from keras.layers import MaxPooling1D
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x=tf.random_normal((1,2,3,3), mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=None, name=None)

h=MaxPooling1D()
h._pooling_function(inputs=x, pool_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1),border_mode="valid", dim_ordering='tf')
```

Is there a way to see the output of this?

Comment: You can get the output of any layer by following below procedure. (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer). You can simply construct a model with only the layer you want to inspect and check its output.

Comment: I did not realize that is how it worked - thanks!!

Comment: I am posting my comment as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example based off of Krishna's comment:

First, we need to build and train a small model - here is one I quickly threw together.

```
    import numpy as np
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
    from keras.layers import Embedding
    from keras.layers import Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
    from keras import backend as K
    from keras.layers.convolutional import ZeroPadding2D

    #FIT A SIMPLE MODEL

    N = 50
    X = np.random.randn(N, 3,5, 5)  #creates the 3 channel data, 5x5 matrices
    y = np.random.randint(1, size=N)

    model = Sequential()

    # number of convolutional filters, this is the number of "neurons"
    n_filters = 2

    # convolution filter size
    # i.e. we will use a n_conv x n_conv filter
    n_conv = 3

    # pooling window size
    # i.e. we will use a n_pool x n_pool pooling window
    n_pool = 2

    # we have a 5x5 image with RGB channel
    # so the input shape should be (3,5,5)
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(input_shape=(3, 5, 5),padding=(1,1)))  #this makes a 7x7 data input

    model.add(Convolution2D(

            n_filters, n_conv, n_conv,

            # apply the filter to only full parts of the image
            # (i.e. do not "spill over" the border)
            # this is called a narrow convolution
            border_mode='valid',


            subsample=(2, 2) #this is STRIDE (left to right and top to bottom),

    ))

    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(n_pool, n_pool)))

    # flatten the data for the 1D layers
    model.add(Flatten())

    # Dense(n_outputs)
    model.add(Dense(10))


    # the softmax output layer gives us a probablity for each class
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))

    model.compile(loss='mse',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'])

    print (model.summary())



    # how many examples to look at during each training iteration
    batch_size = 1

    # how many times to run through the full set of examples
    n_epochs = 1

    model.fit(X,
              y,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=n_epochs)

____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
zeropadding2d_15 (ZeroPadding2D) (None, 3, 7, 7)       0           zeropadding2d_input_13[0][0]     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_18 (Convolution2D) (None, 2, 3, 3)       56          zeropadding2d_15[0][0]           
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_30 (Activation)       (None, 2, 3, 3)       0           convolution2d_18[0][0]           
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_18 (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 2, 1, 1)       0           activation_30[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_12 (Flatten)             (None, 2)             0           maxpooling2d_18[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)                 (None, 10)            30          flatten_12[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)                 (None, 1)             11          dense_20[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_31 (Activation)       (None, 1)             0           dense_21[0][0]                   
====================================================================================================
Total params: 97
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/1
50/50 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.3463 - acc: 0.6000     

<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f4927a66f10>
```

Function to return the array passed into a layer and the output of the layer to examine how a layer actually works on it's input (X is the small data you pass into the layer of interest and the index is determined from the summary above (zero based of course):

```
def input_output (layer_index,X):
    get_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[layer_index].input], [model.layers[layer_index].output])
    layer_output = get_layer_output([X])[0]
    return (X,layer_output)
```

Create small tensor replicating the shape of data coming into the Convolution2D (second layer,index =1)

```
    x=np.random.randn(1,3,7, 7)

    input,output =input_output(1,x)

#After the convolution (shape is 1, 2, 3, 3)
    output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output of any layer by following below procedure. (keras.io/getting-started/faq/…). You can simply construct a model with only the layer you want to inspect and check its output.